# How do I see a Unix Job's performance (execution time and cpu resource) after execution?

Tags: performance, unix, testing, jobs

I have an incoming task that tells me to do performance testing on a unix job. I would like to know if there's something in UNIX that would tell me of a job's performance (execution time and cpu resource)? I plan to do a before and after comparison.

Comment: You can try and use the `time` command for a crude first approximation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linux profile tool `perf`, eg:

```
perf stat ls
```

In my computer:

```
 Performance counter stats for 'ls':

      2.066571 task-clock                #    0.804 CPUs utilized          
             1 context-switches          #    0.000 M/sec                  
             0 CPU-migrations            #    0.000 M/sec                  
           267 page-faults               #    0.129 M/sec                  
     2,434,744 cycles                    #    1.178 GHz                     [57.78%]
     1,384,929 stalled-cycles-frontend   #   56.88% frontend cycles idle    [52.01%]
     1,035,939 stalled-cycles-backend    #   42.55% backend  cycles idle    [98.96%]
     1,894,339 instructions              #    0.78  insns per cycle        
                                         #    0.73  stalled cycles per insn
       370,865 branches                  #  179.459 M/sec                  
        14,280 branch-misses             #    3.85% of all branches        

   0.002569026 seconds time elapsed
```